# Select range of rows to delete in Excel 2007. Runtime error 1004?

Tags: excel, range, delete-row, vba

I'm trying to write a code that deletes all rows between the 3rd and last data row on a worksheet. I have some short lines of code that first looks for the last row containing data, returns that row number. Subtracts 1 from it. And selects the data range from 3rd row to the 2nd to last row and attempts to delete them. But I run into error every time I run this code. Any suggestions?

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
lastrow = (Sheet1.Range("A1").Offset(Sheet1.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Row) - 1
Range("3: lastrow").Select  'Error 1004: method range of object _global failed
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `SpecialCells` property of the range:

```
 Range("A3:" & Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Address).Select
```

This will select the block up until the last used cell.

Edit:
To incorporate it into your program to get the second to last, do some string manipulations on the last cell.

```
Dim str, str1, str2, add As String
Dim index, num As Integer
str = Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Address   'returns say $j$20

index = InStr(2, str, "$")  'find the second dollar sign

str1 = Left(str, index)     'gets the string "$j$"
str2 = Mid(str, index + 1)  'get the string "20" 

num = CInt(str2) 'convert "20" to 20
num = num - 1
add = str1 & CStr(num) 'reattach to form "$j$19"

Range("A3:" & add).Select
```

Comment: Thanks. I need the row right above the last row, how do I specify this. Sorry I'm new to vba

Comment: @jerry I put some comments in there since you're new to it (there's also probably a lot of other ways to do it, too)

Comment: Thank you so much, I realize you have to "save" each time you make a change to your spread sheet that changes the position of the last row. if you want to let the code realize which line is last or second to last.

Comment: Just out of curiosity Why did you think My code did not compile or work?

Comment: @jerry If you use the `xlUp` direction, you have to start at `Range("A65536").End(xlUp)` and you would want the `.Row` not the `.Rows` (I forget what the latter gives you, but it's not correct, double check it on MSDN).  This would only give you one column, so if the columns were uneven, it would cause problems.  The `SpecialCells` is a nice feature of the range (with a different argument to it you can get all the used cells, for instance).

Comment: Hey Jonsca, Sometimes your code selects past the last line of data.

Comment: I wrote some more codes but it keeps giving me another error. Any ideas?

Comment: heres my question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861620/select-range-between-3rd-and-2nd-to-last-row-runtime-error-13-type-mismatch

Comment: @jerry If you have other data in the spreadsheet, it's going to pick up on whatever the last _used_ row and column are.  The approach I outlined will work if the block of data is the only information on the sheet.  The code can be adapted to just grab the block, just specify the range to search more closely `str = Range("A1:M33").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Address` will find the last used cell within that range.